# PHP descending an array stored from foreach loop values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have a foreach loop like this

```
$ids = array();
foreach( $idsvalues as $idv ){
    $ids[$idv->id][] = $idv->value;
}
```

and i get an array like this

```
Array ( [21] => 10 [13] => 16 [12] => 20 [7] => 28 )
```

now how do i descending this array() values only from lowest to highest without effecting the array keys or id?
to show like this

```
Array ( [21] => 28 [13] => 20 [12] => 16 [7] => 10 );
```

the array can contain upto 100 such ids and values so basically just descending the values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to preserve the keys, transfer them to a separate array by using `array_keys` now `rsort` your array (i.e. descending order) , Make use of `array_combine` to link the grabbed keys and descending sorted values.

```
<?php
$arr=Array ( 21 => 10, 13 => 16, 12 => 20, 7 => 28 );
$k_arr=array_keys($arr);
rsort($arr);
$new_arr=array_combine($k_arr,$arr);
print_r($new_arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [21] => 28
    [13] => 20
    [12] => 16
    [7] => 10
)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/102618)

Comment: Array ( [21] => 28 [13] => 20 [12] => 16 [7] => 10 ), Shokrya @Shankar your solution is correcto.